# Hiding plain text URL in JS (Webhook URL)

Tags: javascript, discord, hide

I am working on an electron JS based app, and I have a a discord webhook that logs the happenings. When the ASAR is unpacked (which anyone with knowledge can do), I can find the webhook url in the program which could be abused by users. Is there an easy way to hide it? Using encrypted strings?

I am very much a noob at this kind of stuff.

Comment: Why can this URL be abused? You can generally never trust the client, if you encrypt it and your client can decrypt it then anyone can decrypt it because they simply can extract the decryption part out of your client code.

Comment: the url logs actions for people and mods to see. Someone could just paste the webhook URL somewhere else and spam it with messages, which is what I'm trying to avoid but may be impossible.

Secondly, while the user base may be smart enough to unpack and asar and use the "search" feature I don't think they're smart enough to attempt any kind of decryption at all. @luk2302